# Whynopadlock.com shows one insecure link on microsoft website. Does that mean that htts communication can be compromised?

Tags: tls

The question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728507/finding-all-insecure-content-on-a-secure-page) from stack overflow.

Can anyone explain when I enter https://microsoft.com to https://www.whynopadlock.com url input form there is 1 insecure url detected.

Does this mean that the whole page can be compromised because of that link?

[image]

---

Some additional googling on trans_pixel.aspx:

- Windows 8.1 apps use process named WWAHost.exe that uses HTTP and HTTPS to communicate with several Microsoft webservices such as: ..., http//c.microsoft.com/trans_pixel.aspx ([Windows 8.1 Inside Out](https://books.google.by/books?id=yLxCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT106&lpg=PT106&dq=microsoft%20trans_pixel.aspx&source=bl&ots=r2BfmVepL4&sig=wWZ6Rts-JwLatGLa7leh5hhdtKY&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ0bqNyr7LAhUqEpoKHUxnBcsQ6AEIUzAI#v=onepage&q=microsoft%20trans_pixel.aspx&f=false));
- Virus total https service report ([can be found here](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/aba7b128fa33b77e46df08d9436c773091f33a64f185c8f8f001b23335409d7b/analysis/)), C-SIRT: "Malicious site", but all the rest URL Scanners say that this is a "Clean site" Analysis date:    2014-11-28 13:02:44 UTC ( 1 year, 3 months ago );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the page's source code, you can see there's an image element loaded if the browser has JavaScript disabled

```
<noscript><img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="http://c.microsoft.com/trans_pixel.aspx" /></noscript>
```

I'm believe this is a tracking/analytics element from Microsoft as a fallback for their JavaScript-based tracking script when JavaScript is disabled. If you browse to that page and check your console, you wouldn't see anything out of the ordinary. However, if you disable JavaScript, you'll see this warning:
[image]

Having a non-TLS resource in an HTTPS page is referred to as having [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content). This exposes these requests to tampering by a [man-in-the-middle MiTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to inject JavaScript, CSS, or just plain HTML in the loaded page. Even with benign elements such as `<img>`, an attacker is able to sniff the cookies sent with these non-TLS HTTP requests.

So, **is the connection here compromised?** I don't think so; being an image element, loaded if JS is disabled, and it's on a separate domain, all makes unlikely for this to be an issue. However, Microsoft should know better than to have mixed content.